# which is greater? O(log*n) or O(loglog n)

Tags: algorithm

I have a confusion between the time complexities **O(log*n)** and **O(loglog n)** and wanted to know which one is greater.

Any help?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dlog%28x%29+and+y%3D%28log+log+x%29

Comment: @l19 has the wrong input. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log%28n%29n%2C+log%28log+%28n%29%29

Comment: What is the mathematical definition of `log*n`. I’ve never seen that notation. Is that `log(n)⋅n` or `log(n)` or something else?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei i agree ... but from a numerical perspective, is there a definitive conclusion as to which is greater always or in most cases?

Comment: @Chronial its the Ackerman function alpha(n). look it up .... it is the running time of the Union/Find technique used widely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`O(log* n)` is faster than `O(log log n)` after some threshold.

`log* n` says how many times you need to do `log*(log n)` before it reaches < 1. So it will be 1 + [`log*`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) of what is left from running `log(log n)` until `log N` < 1

So the calculation of this value is recursive.

For `n = 2^512`
`log*n` will give you 4
where as `log log n` = 5.17

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: Sorry, i think it's true for all numbers. It will be less then 1. But log* will be 1

Comment: so you are saying that O(loglog n) is faster no matter what the value of n is? I agree with the logic that O(log*n) will represent the number of time we have to perform log to reach 1. So for small n like 10, (loglog n) < 1, whereas log*n > 1 ..... still confused as to the threshold that I can infer wherein the transition occurs from log*n being greater to loglog n being greater

Comment: ok just so that i am clear .... loglog n will be < 1 for small n but > 1 for larger n. However log*n will always be > 1 as long as n > 2. So how can we conclude that loglog n > log*n always?

Comment: now i am completely confused :( .... can you tell me your thought process on the same?

Comment: ok ... so would you agree that for smaller n, log*n dominates, while for larger n, loglog n dominates?

Comment: loglog n is faster then log*n for all positive numbers

Comment: @VikramBhat yes, I agree with you.

Comment: fixed my answer, so later people are not confused. BTW, I was doing log base 10, which was quite misleading, but I had an intuition that log* n should be faster. Follow your intuition! :)

Answer (score 1):

`O(log*N) < O(loglogN)` for sufficiently large input. log*n is defined as taking log of number till it amounts to 1. The inverse function of log*n is a tower of 2 to power of 2's which increases extremely fast hence log*n grows very slowly. For example `log*(2^65536) = 5`. In comparsion `loglogn` grows faster than `log*n` as an example `log(log(2^65536)) = log(65536) = 32`.

```
Proof:- log*n < loglogn for sufficiently large n

log*n = log*(log(n)) + 1

log*(log(n)) + 1 < log(logn)   

Can easily prove that log*(n) + 1 < logn
replacing n by logn
log*(logn) + 1 < log(logn)
log*(n) < log(logn)
```